# How to map 2 subclass with 1 parent abstract class in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an abstract base class that have 2 subclasses. Each subclass has a table mapped into it whereas the base class doesn't. In order for me to map into Hibernate, I do this:

In subclassA.hbm.xml

```
<class name="BaseClass" abstract="true">
  <id name="theid" type="string" column="THE_ID" lenght="15"/>

  <union-subclass name="SubClassA" table="TABLE_A">
     ...
  </union-subclass>
</class>
```

Same thing goes to `SubClassB`.

In subclassB.hbm.xml

```
<class name="BaseClass" abstract="true">
  <id name="theid" type="string" column="THE_ID" lenght="15"/>

  <union-subclass name="SubClassB" table="TABLE_B">
     ...
  </union-subclass>
</class>
```

The id is a member variable in `BaseClass`, and `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` both have `THE_ID` field in it. I get a runtime error mention that the `BaseClass` has **duplicate mapping**.

May I know how can I do the Hibernate mapping when I have two subclasses?

Answer (score 2):

define `SubClassB` inside your `BaseClass` definition, alongside `SubClassA` definition.

Comment: Is that means SubClassB and SubClassA are member variable of BaseClass?

Comment: no, they don't have to be member variables. they just have to be defined in hibernate mapping under your base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two mapping files if you create two classes:

```
public class SubClassA extends BaseClass {
}

public class SubClassB extends BaseClass {
}
```

The bodies of the classes can be empty or they can have extra member variables (They only need the default parameterless constructor, which they have if you don't write another constructor). In the hibernate mapping you can access the member variables of the parent class (even the private member variables!).

Then you simply write two mapping files subclassA.hbm.xml

```
<class name="SubClassA" >
   <id name="theid" type="string" column="THE_ID" lenght="15"/>
   ...
</class>
```

and subclassB.hbm.xml

```
<class name="SubClassB">
  <id name="theid" type="string" column="THE_ID" lenght="15"/>
  ...
</class>
```

P. S. In this scenario you must *not* map BaseClass. Hibernate gets confused if both the superclass and the subclass are mapped.